# Good project template for new Django 1.6 project?

Tags: python, django, openid

Could someone suggest the good project template for new Django 1.6 project?

I need:

1. Simple base page layout with menu, content and footers – on bootstrap or something like it.
2. User accounts: with social authorization (facebook, g+, Mozilla persona) and self registering with e-mail account activation
3. User profile (change email-password-avatar)
4. Simple user messages and comments
5. CKeditor (or some another js-editor) widgets included
6. Django 1.6+ and Python 3.3+

I’ve looked on pinax, but it’s a lot of templates, not an “all-in-one”.

Comment: You can find all you need in this answer  [Django project structure][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22841764/best-practice-for-django-project-working-directory-structure

Comment: I've readed the suggested topic, but it have NO answer. I need the project template with described functions. I think, it should be a pinax, but it doesn't run on Python 3.3, only on 2.7