# Django project structure

Tags: python, django

I've been playing with Django for a couple of weeks and I decided to try to make my personal website with it.

The only thing I can't yet wrap my head around is how I should structure the project. The essential of the site will be a blog-like portfolio that shows `projects`. Those projects (comparable to categories on normal blogs) will contain posts about them.

Now my question is, should that be 1 big app or should I divide this into multiple smaller apps and in that case how would **you** do it?

*For now it looks acceptable to have everything in one app, but my plan is to add features along the way and expand the site continuously. After some time I don't exclude the possibility that it could get pretty complex :)*

---

**Response to the fact that this question has been closed because it is "mostly opinion based"..**

I am asking for experience (that I don't yet have), to be able to make a better choice about how I should structure my project in order to avoid having to restructure it later because I made a bad choice due to a lack of experience. Of course this requires some opinion based answers..

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22841764/best-practice-for-django-project-working-directory-structure

Comment: Thank you, I already found that thread. But my problem is not so much with the directory structure, I have already done extensive research about that. My question is more about **when do you know when to split an app into multiple apps** and **how you would do that**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you only have one category of *articles*, I recommend you to start with one application.

Hence, you can start with an application named `projects`. Then, if you want to write about your experiences, create a new application named `experiences`, and so on.

Personally, my portfolio is built around three categories/applications:

1. Skills,
2. Projects,
3. Experiences.

Applications are ideal for large Django websites. I advise you to add applications to your project when it becomes bigger and more complex. For now, make your life easier by using only one application ;)

Comment: Great :) How easy is it to divide one app into multiple apps later on if I  need to?

Comment: In fact, you do not need to divide one application into multiple applications. From the start, create a Django project with ``django-admin.py startproject portfolio``and then create a dedicated application for your projects with ``manage.py startapp projects``. Put all stuff about your projects into this application. When you need to present something completly different from your projects, start a new application. If you can't follow this guideline, dividing an application into multiple applications is a kind of refactoring, not something specific to Django itself.