# Why can't I import modules in a Django project?

Tags: python, django, import, django-dev-server

I am trying to pick up an old Django project and my immediate goal is to see what I can get running on my computer on the development server. I get:

```
Inner Sanctum ~/pragmatometer $ python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in 
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
    commands = get_commands()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 107, in get_commands
    apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 54, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 49, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 132, in __init__
    % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e)
ImportError: Could not import settings 'pragmatometer.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named pragmatometer.settings
```

Here is some command line output:

```
Inner Sanctum ~/pragmatometer $ /bin/pwd
/Users/jonathan/pragmatometer
Inner Sanctum ~/pragmatometer $ echo $PYTHONPATH
/Users/jonathan
Inner Sanctum ~/pragmatometer $ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 14 2015, 19:46:27) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pragmatometer
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
ImportError: No module named pragmatometer
>>> import pragmatometer.settings
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
ImportError: No module named pragmatometer.settings
>>>
```

What should I be doing that I'm not? (Or, as it was an older project, should I just start with a fresh new project?)

Thanks,

Comment: Is the pragmatometer directory a package (does it have a `__init__.py` file) and is there a settings module somewhere inside there (does it have a `settings.py` file)?

Comment: ls *.py output: 
__init__.py manage.py settings.py views.py
functions.py models.py urls.py

Comment: And if you try to `import pragmatometer.settings` from `~`?

Answer (score 0):

every django project comes with a settings.py file, and django will refuse to run, or load models, until that settings.py file is loaded.

settings.py file needs to be in a module and part of your current PYTHONPATH, and
env. variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE should be set to it.

For example:

```
# assuming your file is under /myproject/mywebsite/settings.py
export PYTHONPATH=/myproject/
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mywebsite.settings
```

Answer (score 0):

A Django project normally looks something like this (as of Django 1.4 and above, I think).

```
myproject
    myproject
        __init__.py
        settings.py
    app1
    app2
```

You can [look](https://github.com/kirpit/django-sample-app) [around](http://www.revsys.com/blog/2014/nov/21/recommended-django-project-layout/) [online](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23469321/25507) for examples and variations on this.

Note that there's a `myproject` directory, containing settings, under the top-level `myproject`.

Does yours look at all like this?

Or did you originally target an older version of Django that uses a different layout?

If you try to do this:

```
PYTHONPATH=/Users/jonathan python
import pragmatometer
```

like in your second code block, it's going to treat `/Users/jonathan` as a Python package and look for `/Users/jonathan/__init__.py`, which probably doesn't exist), so it won't check `/Users/jonathan/pragmatometer/settings.py`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the culprit, or at least a culprit. I had omitted (in my .bashrc) the "export ", and now I'm on to another problem.