# Django relative import of project settings causing errors in moved manage.py file

Tags: python, django

Following the directory structure in the answer here:

[Best practice for Django project working directory structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22841764/best-practice-for-django-project-working-directory-structure)

Reviewed the code on GitHub here to troubleshoot:

[django-start-template](https://github.com/tricoder42/django-start-template)

I moved the `manage.py` into a `scripts` directory. I modified the `manage.py` and `wsgi.py` to have these lines:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "{{ project_name }}.settings")
```

Instead of the default:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "proj_dir.settings")
```

Which I think is basically equivalent.

Anyway, this is the error I get when I run `python manage.py runserver`:

```
  File "C:\Users\ISH~1\DJANGO~1\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 944, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 944, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named '{{ project_name }}'
```

I have tried using relative imports, but really not getting anywhere to resolve the issue. Being a newb, I am sure the answer is pretty obvious, but I have spent a few hours reading about the problem and not really getting anywhere.

One suggested adding `from . import *` but this just resulted in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import *
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

`virtualenv` is active and I running `manage.py` from the correct directory. Works fine when it is not in `/scripts/`.

EDIT:

I didn't mentioned this, but regardless of whether in `manage.py` it is:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "proj_dir.settings")
```

Or:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "{{ project_name )).settings")
```

The result is always `ImportError: No Module named 'xyz'`. Fill in `xyz` with anything before `settings`.

Also, the above indicates, my project isn't 100% implemented like what is discussed in the first link. My `settings.py` is still in the default location. It looks like this basically:

```
~/projects/django-project

/proj_dir
    settings.py
    urls.py
    wsgi.py
/scripts
    manage.py
```

Also, I tried this because I thought well it might be looking for `proj_dir` in `scripts` and I actually want it to go up a level to look for `proj_dir`.

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", ".proj_dir.settings")
```

This just brings up the following error.

```
TypeError: the 'package' argument is required to perform a relative import for '.proj_dir.settings'
```

That is when I started messing around with `import` and `from . import` because documentation was saying the error was related to that. Still couldn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have moved `manage.py` to the `scripts` directory, you will have to explicitly add the parent directory to the python path.

```
sys.path.append('..')
```

The line that sets the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable should not be changed. Keep it as

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "proj_dir.settings")
```

Comment: Hallelujah... that did the trick. Knew it was something simple.

Answer (score 0):

"{{ project_name }}" appears to be a placeholder - manage.py isn't a template, and you are not using template syntax to place a variable in the string for os.environ.setdefault().

You need to use the correct project name/name of the module. In the example repo, the correct project name would be "project_name" (no braces), e.g. "project_name.settings.development" if you were using the development settings as named in that repo.

The error you see indicates the behavior clearly, as it is looking for a module named "{{ project_name }}" as that is the top-level (separated by dot) python module name provided, and it does not exist.

Comment: Thanks, please see the edits. I realized I didn't explain myself quite well enough.