# Django - provide changed path for settings.py

Tags: python, django, configuration

For easier collaboration I changed the directory structure of an existing django-project like this:

```
├── docs
├── manage.py
├── requirements.txt
├── static
│   └── my_app
│       ├── css
│       ├── fonts
│       ├── img
│       └── js
├── templates
│   └── my_app
└── proj_name
    ├── apps
    │   └── my_app
    │       ⋮
    │       └── views.py
    ├── settings
    │   └── base.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── wsgi.py
```

#### Part of the settings-file base.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))), '..')
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'the actual secret key'
```

### Using manage.py throws errors

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

**django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.**
To figure out the problem more exactly I ran `check` which actually throws a different error

```
python manage.py check
```

**django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.**

Before changing the directory-structure the project worked.

#### How to change the path for django-project settings-file?

---

Directory restructuring inspired by
[Best practice for Django project working directory structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22841764/best-practice-for-django-project-working-directory-structure)

Comment: are you using the settings_yaml?

Comment: No, I edited the django-generated python configuration file `settings.py` and renamed it to `base.py` in order to import it to `production.py`

Comment: Show me your conf directory are you using fabric for deploy

Comment: proj_name/settings/base.py is main settings file. Python also produced 
__init __.py there and folder __pycache __

Comment: Put it the post mate I don't understand anything in the comment

Comment: You're right. Updated post. The config is done in the settings-file `proj_name/settings/base.py`