# In Django, does the intermediate model need to belong in the same file as the target model?

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many, django-orm, django-migrations

When running a migration, I am currently getting this *lazy reference ValueError* whenever the model that I have a defined ManyToManyField is in a separate file from the model that I am targeting. However, when I place the two models in the same file, I am able to successfully run the mirgation.

1. Why is this error happening?
2. Is it possible to separate the models (community.py and community_member.py) into separate files?

> ValueError:  contains a
>   lazy reference to fitness.communitymember, but app 'fitness' doesn't
>   provide model 'communitymember'.

My directory structure looks like this:

```
my_app
  |----fitness
       |----user.py
       |----community.py
       |----community_member.py
```

**community.py**

```
class Community(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(
        primary_key=True,
    )
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
    )
    members = models.ManyToManyField(
        User,
        through='CommunityMember',
        through_fields=('community', 'member')
    )

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Communities'
```

**community_member.py**

```
class CommunityMember(models.Model):
    community = models.ForeignKey(
        Community,
        db_column='community_id'
    )
    member = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        db_column='member_id',
    )

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Community_Members'
```

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'my_app.fitness'
]
```

If I place the contents of **community_members.py** inside of **community.py** the migration is successfully executes, but I am not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rashed, I really don't know why you need to split your models, but if you insisted in doing so, there must be a reason. A default Django's app must include a `models.py` file. The `ValueError` comes from the fact Django is unable to find all your models definitions, it simple doesn't know where to look for these models. If you insist in doing so (which I personally don't recommend with only two models) you should do what the docummentation recommends: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#organizing-models-in-a-package

Comment: Thank you @gmacro. I'm fairly new to Django, and splitting up models into multiple files is a pattern taken from other frameworks. The #organizing-models-in-a-package section in the Django docs fixed my problem.

Also, I did not realize it was a Django anti-pattern to split models across different files. By default, models should live in models.py, and if not, it is recommended to create a separate app directory anyway.

Thanks again.

Comment: @Rashadm, wish you all the luck in your new "Django journey", hope you enjoy it. Django is very well documented, if you have a doubt, it's probably there. Take a look at this answer, it will help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22841764/best-practice-for-django-project-working-directory-structure