# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project.user'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

If anyone knows how to solve this, please don't hesitate to help. I've tried many hints, but so far this problem still remains. Too frustrating!

I just started a little project on Django because I want to test [Django Rest Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/). I created a project called `project` and inside it an app called `user`.

After that, I created a directory called `api` inside `user` and then I created the files `viewsets.py` and `serializers.py` in order to test Django Rest Framework.

[image]

In urls.py I imported "UsuarioViewSet" class from viewsets.

```
from project.user.api.viewsets import UsuarioViewSet
```

[image]

When I run `python manage.py runserver` the problem bellow ocurrs

[image]

(I also tried only `user.api.viewsets`... but it says "unresolved reference")

In my `settings.py` I registered 'user' and 'rest_framework':

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'user',
]
```

OS: Linux Mint |
IDE: PyCharm (community) |
Virtualenv: venv |
Python: 3.6.6

Comment: You should use `from user.api.viewsets import UsuarioViewSet` instead of `from project.user.api.viewsets import UsuarioViewSet`

Comment: I've already tried this way. As I said in my post, when I use like this, it says "unresolved reference".

Comment: Can you paste the traceback of unresolved reference, this seems to be some other problem apart from this import error.

Comment: try this for the unresolved reference - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236824/unresolved-reference-issue-in-pycharm)

Comment: Why is there no `__init__.py` in the user directory? (`user/__init__.py`)?

Comment: Yes, your manage.py is outside your project dir. Your Django project structured is screwed up. Please read this for better understanding of Django project layout: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22841764/best-practice-for-django-project-working-directory-structure

Comment: "Unresolved reference 'user' less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Inspection info: This inspection detects names that should resolve but don't. Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing, this is possible in a limited but useful number of cases. Top-level and class-level items are supported better than instance items."

Comment: `__init__.py` in `user/` already exists. Look.

Comment: YAY! Thanks @fmakawa
This link really fixed my problem! I'm very greateful. Thanks to everyone who tried to help me!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this kind of thing happens because of migration file `__init__.py`.
The main reason for this is when you write code and make changes in the migration file and then you remove some part from code for which a migrate file has been already  created.

So a solution is just delete `__init__.py` from migration
and make sure that there is no other import which is removed or changed.