# django directory structure the "django way"? (/root/project/app or /root/project & root/app)?

Tags: django

I have a pretty simple question here:

I'm starting out with Django but i'm needing to know which one of the following is more proper (the django way):

1. Having the app under the django_project like this: `/root/project/app`
2. Or Having the Django_project and the django_app under the same `/root/` directory in parallel?

Comment: A project may consist of many apps. I suggest you to read a Django tutorial first and follow the best practice recommended in that tutorial.

Comment: Having the app under the django_project like this: /root/project/app

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best practice for Django project working directory structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22841764/best-practice-for-django-project-working-directory-structure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several thoughts of how to do this best, and only you and your team can find out what works best for you. The Django tutorial recommends keeping apps in parallel to the configuration directory. My team has settled on a few things over time:

From the project root:

```
.gitignore
manage.py
README.md
+---config
    +---urls.py
    +---wsgi.py
    +---settings.py
+---requirements
+---templates
+---static
+---app1
    +---models.py, etc
+---app2
```

Some prefer another directory layer above the project level, but that has felt like overkill to our projects. We have settled as a team on naming each project's configuration subdirectory `config`, rather than the project name repeated. This is just personal preference, but has worked for us. Good luck!

Comment: Did you make your project name “config”?

Comment: I didn't; if I run `django-admin startproject myproject`, the first thing I do it rename the subdirectory `myproject` to be `config`, and edit `config/settings.py` to replace instances of `myproject` with `config`, such as `myproject.urls` becoming `config.urls`. That way, all of our projects have their configurations in the same subdirectory.

Comment: Wouldn’t doing ‘Django-admin startproject config .’ have the same effect?

Comment: Six of one, half-dozen of another: there are some comments in the boilerplate that also insert the project name. But yes, probably easier that way, as they are just comments. Good idea!