# Designing a multi-type user webapp in django

Tags: django

Im building a webapp in django and really beating myself over the design im going to use. This is a big project and it needs to be scalable and so the design is critical.

My app will have two main types of users, each of them have to see some similar elements, but their 'Flow' through the website and the interaction with it should be different depending on the user type.

I read the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22841764/best-practice-for-django-project-working-directory-structure) and considered using [this](https://github.com/arocks/edge) skeleton project. But non of them address the fact that I have 2 different types of users.

And so my question is:
is it best practice to have a user/profile app, then app for each one of the entities. or on the other hand have a user app that contains all user related and have user groups deciding which kind of user it is, then the main app will decide which flow to show the user depending on its group.

Any other design best practices will be great.