# How to fix absolute import problem in Django?

Tags: python, django, import

I try to figure it out why can't I import a module but I have no success. My structure is very simple:

```
exitinterview
firm
stressz
    -models.py
performance
    -emails.py
```

I want to import `Projects` class from `stressz.models` into `emails.py` like this:

```
from stressz.models import Project
```

But I always get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stressz'
```

I have `stressz` in my `settings.py` in the `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: if you are using python 3 then try `from .stressz.models import Project`... a dot(.) before the stressz.

Comment: Yes, I'm tried. In this case: `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Comment: try with ..(two dots)

Comment: have you set the root directory in settings.py?

Answer (score 0):

You do not mention where your project folder is.

If you follow this structure, you should solve this issue:

```
.
manage.py
├── app1
     └── models.py
├── app2
     └── models.py
└── project
     └── settings.py
```

For more best practice in working directory, you can read more here:
[Best practice for Django project working directory structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22841764/best-practice-for-django-project-working-directory-structure)